# App looks like DialogFragment

Tags: android

When I open my Application  (either run it from Android studio itself or after I installed it and start it from the phone) it looks like this.

I blurred out the contents for reasons ;) still it is very weird.

[image]

Manifest

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.jacobusconradi.versuchstestapplication" >

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />


    <application
      android:allowBackup="true"
      android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
      android:label="@string/app_name"
      android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >

      <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >

        <intent-filter>
          <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
          <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
      </activity>


      <activity
        android:name=".NASA_TLX_Test"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:configChanges="locale"
        android:label="Nasa TLX Test" >
      </activity>
    </application>
  </manifest>
```

activity_main.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/LayoutContainer"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/LinearLayout1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        tools:context="versuchstest.versuchstestapp.MainActivity" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="80dp"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_below="@+id/textView3"
            android:src="@drawable/fraunhoferlogo" />

        <View
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="1px"
            android:background="@android:color/black" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/ueberschrift"
            android:layout_width="281dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Name der Versuchsperson"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/editText1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:ems="10" >

            <requestFocus />
        </EditText>

        <View
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="1px"
            android:background="@android:color/black" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Testbedingung"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/editText2"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:ems="10" />

        <View
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="1px"
            android:background="@android:color/black" />

        <CheckBox
            android:id="@+id/checkBox1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Erklärung ausblenden" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/startTest"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_weight="0.00"
        android:text="starten" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

How do I make it look like an actual activity?

*Note: **NOT** like a `DialogWindow`*

*If any additional questions exist, I will update it, so you can get the informations you need :)*

Comment: What is your requirement?

Comment: Post your style that your references here **android:theme="@style/AppTheme".** You've probably used the wrong `parent style`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OK so here is the solution to this Problem:

In styles.xml (v21) i had:

```
<resources>
<style name="AppTheme" parent="android:Theme.Material.Dialog.NoActionBar">
</style>
</resources>
```

Instead of :

```
<resources>
<style name="AppTheme" parent="android:Theme.Material.NoActionBar">
</style>
</resources>
```